# Do I Need to Rebuild a Subversion Repo From Scratch?

Tags: svn

I apologize for some basic questions, I'm a BSEE who writes firmware and my IT/admin skills are pretty poor. Long story, but at my last company we had a server with a SVN repo on it. My new company acquired the assets of the old company, including the source code in this repo. However, rather than use the SVNAdmin tools to do a dump/import or even a hotcopy, what IT at the old company gave me was just a ZIP of the contents of the repo. I've tried doing an import into the new repo I created by pointing to the unzipped copy of the repo contents I have locally, but I get an error that it's not a path to a valid Subversion directory (which makes sense - it's just a local folder).

So how do I rebuild this repo on my new server?

Answer (score 0):

Disregard, I wasn't tunneling to a low enough folder level when trying to import.